# Translation of 友達【ともだち】に 嘘【うそ】がばれてしまった

Tags: translation, particles, particle-に

I have some trouble to translate this sentence:

> 友達【ともだち】に 嘘【うそ】がばれてしまった

is that: "I have discovered that my friend is lying" or "My friend found out I was lying"?

---

この文の翻訳に迷っています：

> 友達【ともだち】に 嘘【うそ】がばれてしまった

その文の意味は「友達が嘘をついていることを気づいた」また「友達が私の嘘していることを気づいた」ですか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the sentence says 友達**に**ばれた, it means that your friend found out. There is another hint in the sentence, though: しまった is usually used to convey an unfortunate event/outcome/happening from the point of the speaker. In this case this is your friend finding out about your lie.

To get the other meaning with the least change, we can say

> 友達**の**嘘がばれてしまった
>   my friend's lie was found out

By whom would not be immediate, but it could mean that you found out about your friend's lie.

Comment: thanks for explaing with other example :-). helped a lot